# How to make a parameterized trait which can instantiate classes?

Tags: scala, generics, reflection

I am using the "case class instead of Enumeration" pattern, and want to have a list of all values per "enumeration" as well as a few methods. So I decided to not just derive my case classes from a sealed abstract class, but to derive all the sealed abstract classes from a superclass called Lookup, and to define a LookupTrait from which to derive the abstract classes' companion objects.

```
abstract class Lookup {
  val name: String
  override def toString = name
}

trait LookupTrait[T<:Lookup] {
  val all: Map[String, T]
  val default: T
  def withName(name: String): T = 
    if(all.contains(name)) all(name)
    else default   
}
```

And an example lookup looks like this:

```
sealed case class StudyGoal(override val name: String)  extends Lookup 

object StudyGoal extends LookupTrait[StudyGoal] {

  override val all = Map(
      "present new evaluation method" -> StudyGoal("present new evaluation method"), 
      "evaluate existing product" -> StudyGoal("evaluate existing product"),
      "develop new theoretical model" -> StudyGoal("develop new theoretical model"), 
      "unknown" -> StudyGoal("unknown")
      ) 
   override val default = StudyGoal("unknown")
}
```

I would prefer to simply define a list of strings in the companion object of each lookup and have the trait instantiate the case classes. But while I found three different ways of doing reflection in Scala - using a Manifest, a TypeTag, and getting the constructor of a class as described [in the documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html), all of them seem to require to have an instance of the class present, and I couldn't get them to work within the parameterized LookupTrait trait.

I would like to have something like:

```
abstract class Lookup {
  val name: String
  override def toString = name
}

trait LookupTrait[T<:Lookup] {
  val allNames: List[String] 

  val default: T = //Instantiate a T using the string "unknown". 
  //It is OK that this string will be the same for all Lookups. 

  val all: Map[String, T] = allNames.map(
    n => n -> //instantiate a T here, using n as the parameter
) += default 

  def withName(name: String): T = 
    if(all.contains(name)) all(name)
    else default   
}

sealed case class StudyGoal(override val name: String)  extends Lookup 

object StudyGoal extends LookupTrait[StudyGoal] {

  override val allNames = List(
      "present new evaluation method"), 
      "evaluate existing product",
      "develop new theoretical model"
      ) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a lib that does something close, only you are required to define case objects instead of just using strings: https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum

It's powered by a macro that, with a little work/modification, could possibly result in exactly what you want (at compile-time, define instances based on strings)

Answer (score 0):

So from your comments in your "what I would like to have" section, it looks like you want to further parameterize on "instantiate T". You could add an abstract method to `LookupTrait` that subclasses would need to implement; it could have a signature like:

```
def instantiateElement(name: String): T
```

I'm a little confused about what you're trying to do, though. Scala Enumerations are meant to be used like Java enums - for handling a fixed, finite set of choices. You typically bind each of those elements to a PascalCase name, so that you can later pattern match an unknown value against this set of names. Your case looks less like a fixed, finite set and more like a dynamic, open set. Maybe you don't need any of this at all; maybe a plain `Set[String]` is sufficient.